# Android app to get system phone number

Tags: android, sdk, device, apk

I'm Trying the following code to get System phone number

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

But it is not working.

**In my phone, i use**

> Settings->About Phone-->Status-Phone Number

is there a simple app i can use ? , I m writing from Turkey. does sim card make a difference ?

Comment: If phone number is unknown in Status, then the issue might be about SIM Card. If phone number isn't known in SIM Card then Android or your Android App got nothing to do about it. I suggest you to try it with another SIM Card if possible and look into your problem depending on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. It works perfectly.

```
public  String getPhoneNumber(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String num = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
        return fillPhoneNumber(num);
    }
private   String fillPhoneNumber(String num) {
    try{
        if (num != null && num.length() > 0) {
            if (num.length() >= 9) {
                num = num.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                if (num.substring(0, 1).equals("8")) {
                    num = "+3" + num;
                } else if (num.substring(0, 1).equals("0")) {
                    num = "+38" + num;
                } else if (num.substring(0, 1).equals("3")) {
                    num = "+" + num;
                }
            }
            return num;
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Note:**  Not all phones return a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Not all telecom carriers store the phone number on the SIM card. The approach you are using only works if the SIM card in the device has the mobile number stored on it.

If you cannot see your phone number in the mobile settings, then it means that it isn't stored on the SIM card. You will have to manually ask the user to enter it into your app if you absolutely need it. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no deterministic way to find the MSISDN. The above approach only works if SIM has stored the MSISDN. Other work around is to retrieve the number from facebook. It also may or may not work.
The only sure shot way is to create account with some SMS gateway provider like http://trumpia.com, then send SMS to the toll free number, and then call the API to retrieve the MSISDN.